# Не срабатывает exit в скрипте с условием

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "x$(tail -n+11 $0 | md5sum)" = "x$(head -n10 $0 | tail -n1)" ] || (echo "поврежден"; exit 1);
```

echo "поврежден" пишет, но exit 1 не срабатывает. Как переписать чтоб сработало?

Comment: Переписать на нормальный `if`. Скобки запускают команды в саб-шелле и `exit` выходит из него, а не из основного шелла. Ну, или если очень хочется, то использовать фигурные скобки. `[ ... ] || { echo "..."; exit 1; }`

Comment: `man bash` *Compound Commands*

Comment: хороший вопрос, постоянно тоже сталкиваюсь с подобной проблемой, 
помогает переписать на привычные нам if else fi.
если вдруг кто - нибудь знает решение данного вопроса без переписи условий, дайте знать!

Comment: @AlexeyTen нормальный if плохо читается в одну строку. `{}` то что нужно

Comment: @AlexeyTen добавите ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписать на нормальный `if`. Скобки запускают команды в саб-шелле и `exit` выходит из него, а не из основного шелла.

```bsh
if [ "x$(tail -n+11 $0 | md5sum)" = "x$(head -n10 $0 | tail -n1)" ]; then
    echo "поврежден"
    exit 1
fi
```

Но если очень хочется, то надо использовать фигурные скобки:

```bsh
[ "x$(tail -n+11 $0 | md5sum)" = "x$(head -n10 $0 | tail -n1)" ] || { echo "поврежден"; exit 1; }
```

[Compound Commands](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=bash&category=1&russian=2#lbAO) в bash.